# JSFiddle How to get code running on Run

Tags: jsfiddle

Refer to this JSFiddle demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/MalcollmS/kLt3pfrc/2/

Why isn't my window.onload running?

How do I run the code editor.initialise?

Malcolm

```
var editor = (function () {
    var editorData = {"Weeks":[{"Days":[{"Date":"\/Date(1417611600000)\/","DayIndex":1,"StartHour":0,"StartMin":0,"FinishHour":0,"FinishMin":0,"LunchHour":0},{"Date":"\/Date(1417698000000)\/","DayIndex":2,"StartHour":0,"StartMin":0,"FinishHour":0,"FinishMin":0,"LunchHour":0},{"Date":"\/Date(1417784400000)\/","DayIndex":3,"StartHour":0,"StartMin":0,"FinishHour":0,"FinishMin":0,"LunchHour":0},{"Date":"\/Date(1417870800000)\/","DayIndex":4,"StartHour":0,"StartMin":0,"FinishHour":0,"FinishMin":0,"LunchHour":0},{"Date":"\/Date(1417957200000)\/","DayIndex":5,"StartHour":0,"StartMin":0,"FinishHour":0,"FinishMin":0,"LunchHour":0},{"Date":"\/Date(1418043600000)\/","DayIndex":6,"StartHour":0,"StartMin":0,"FinishHour":0,"FinishMin":0,"LunchHour":0},{"Date":"\/Date(1418130000000)\/","DayIndex":7,"StartHour":0,"StartMin":0,"FinishHour":0,"FinishMin":0,"LunchHour":0}]}],"NumWeeks":1,"WeekEnding":"\/Date(1418130000000)\/","StartDate":"\/Date(1417611600000)\/"}

    initialise = function (data) {
        //editorData = data;

        $("#starthourselector div").live("click", function () { updateEditor("#starthourselector div", this); });
    };

    function updateEditor(selector, div) {
        alert(selector);
        $(selector).css('background-color','red');
        $(div).css('background-color','white');
        //var idx = $(selector).index(div));
    }

    return {
        initialise: initialise
     };
}());


window.onload = function() {
   alert('hi');
    editor.initialise(null);
}
```

Comment: I don't see window.onload on the jsfiddle.

Comment: Still don't see the changes

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MalcollmS/kLt3pfrc/8/

Answer (score 2):

In the jsfiddle option click no wrap head option and it should work properly
    `select no wrap head on the left hand side under on the same dropbox as onLoad`
    [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kLt3pfrc/9/)